# Setting node bounding box size in OGDF

Tags: c++, qt, layout, graph, ogdf

I'm attempting to layout and visualise a code flow graph in Qt using the OGDF library and the Sugiyama layout. The version I'm using is v2020.02, which should be the latest at the time of writing.

**My issue:**
When creating nodes, I set them to various sizes, but after calling the `SugiyamaLayout` algorithm all node sizes are reset to 20x20 (presumably the default?).
If I use another algorithm (such as `PlanarizationLayout`) instead, the issue disappears and node sizes keep their assigned values.
I tried different configurations, such as rankings, crossMins and layouts, but the node size is not affected by those.

**Minimal reproducible example:**

```
//Create graph and attributes
graph_ = new Graph();
GA_ = new GraphAttributes(*graph_, GraphAttributes::nodeGraphics | GraphAttributes::nodeType |
 GraphAttributes::nodeLabel | GraphAttributes::nodeStyle | GraphAttributes::edgeGraphics | 
 GraphAttributes::edgeType | GraphAttributes::edgeArrow);

//Create node and set size
node n = graph_->newNode();
GA_->width(n) = 80; //Or any other dimensions
GA_->height(n) = 40;
//Other nodes and edges omitted

//Create layout
SugiyamaLayout slayout;
slayout.setRanking(new OptimalRanking());
slayout.setCrossMin(new MedianHeuristic());
OptimalHierarchyLayout* ohl = new OptimalHierarchyLayout;
ohl->layerDistance(30.0);
ohl->nodeDistance(25.0);
ohl->weightBalancing(0.8);
slayout.setLayout(ohl);
slayout.call(*GA_);

//Retrieve new node position and size
double x = GA_->x(n);
double y = GA_->y(n);
double w = GA_->width(n);  //This always retrieves w*h of 20x20,
double h = GA_->height(n); //no matter what node dimensions were initially set

//Draw graph, etc. (omitted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, the OGDF Mailing List provided me with the answer.

This behavior is indeed caused by a bug in `HierarchyLayoutModule.h`, where the correct bounding box sizes aren't preserved.

The corresponding Github issue can be found [here](https://github.com/ogdf/ogdf/issues/66) and will be fixed in the next release.
In the meantime, it can be fixed by replacing the `HierarchyLayoutModule::call` method in `\include\ogdf\layered\HierarchyLayoutModule.h` with this code snippet:

```
/**
 * \brief Computes a hierarchy layout of \p levels in \p GA
 * @param levels is the input hierarchy.
 * @param GA is assigned the hierarchy layout.
 */
void call(const HierarchyLevelsBase &levels, GraphAttributes &GA) {
    GraphAttributes AGC(levels.hierarchy());
    // Copy over relevant nodeGraphics attributes that may be used by doCall or need to be preserved
    // edgeGraphics' bend points need to be cleared and aren't copied over
    if (GA.has(GraphAttributes::nodeGraphics)) {
        const GraphCopy &GC = dynamic_cast<const GraphCopy&>(AGC.constGraph());
        for (node vOrig: GA.constGraph().nodes)
        {
            node v = GC.copy(vOrig);
            if (v != nullptr) {
                AGC.height(v) = GA.height(vOrig);
                AGC.width(v) = GA.width(vOrig);
                AGC.shape(v) = GA.shape(vOrig);
            }
        }
    }
    doCall(levels,AGC);
    AGC.transferToOriginal(GA);
}
```